# "Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back" but which transaction?

Tags: mysql

My application logs have been filled up with the logs

> Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back

Is there a way to find a list of transactions that have been started but not completed (committed or rolled-back) yet?

[UPDATE]

With `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` I got the following information

> ---
>
> ### LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
>
> *** (1) TRANSACTION:
> ...  {SQL 1}
> *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
> ...
> *** (2) TRANSACTION:
> ...  {SQL 2}
> *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):

Comment: At first you could examine current innodb state with `show engine innodb status` and `show full processlist` to see what's going on inside db server

Comment: Your code checks for errors after every SQL query, correct?  Keep an eye on `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` -- but its information is transient.

Comment: I have updated my Question with some results from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` command